# Making Subdomain also be secured https://

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, subdomain, auto-generate

I have the wordpress secured site https://novatools.io/ 
This domain auto-generates the subdomain http://abc.novatools.io/
How can I get this subdomain also secured with https:// ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the sub domain secured by using Wildcard SSL certificate. A wildcard SSL certificate allows the main website and its subdomains to be secured by a single SSL certificate, even if the sites are on the multiple servers. Talk to your certificate provider and get Wildcard SSL certificate.